# Prevent mesh from being rendered

Tags: hide, blender, mesh

Is there any way to hide meshes, which have been used as "boolean helper" (e.g. for drilling or such) from render?

1. I'm having a cube and a cylinder. The cylinder is used to cut off something from the cube using boolean difference modifier. This works ok.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a58QK.png]

2. Usually I would delete the cylinder, but experience has shown, that it is way easier to re-facturate a combined mesh in object mode than peeking around in edit mode and try to correct something, if not reorganize everything. That's why I was just hiding the cylinder from display by "closing the eye" in the project folder:

[image]

3. The problem now: If I export the thing to STL for print, the cylinder is still there (which is normal, I would say), but would there be a way to "hide" it from the export by configuration? So that I wouldn't have to delete all my boolean helper objects and being unable then to comfortably change the model afterwards.

View in Prusa Slicer:

[image]

Working with Blender 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Was sure, I did try that already. Didn't work for me the first time, but in fact, it works as described.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205547/how-to-prevent-hidden-shapes-from-being-exported-to-stl-file